# Access Request mail should be sent only to the owner of the Library but not to the Site Collection Admins

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, access, sharepoint-email

I have created a Document Library and assigned **User x** the owner of that Document Library. Now, I want that, whenever any other user request for access to that particular library, the request mail should only be sent to **User X** but not the Site Collection Administrators.

Is it possible to configure O365 so that it can meet my requirements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible to change any of the default functionality of access request emails in SPO.